# What is the best format to export bigger output?

Tags: database, powershell, fileserver

I have a big file server, with a big files and folder tree and I need export the NTFS permissions. I used a following script:

```
$FolderPath = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\FS -Filter * -Recurse -Force 

ForEach ($Folder in $FolderPath) {
  $Acl = Get-Acl -Path $Folder.FullName
  ForEach ($Access in $Acl.Access) {
    $Properties = [ordered]@{'Folder Name'=$Folder.FullName;'Group/User'=$Access.IdentityReference;'Permissions'=$Access.FileSystemRights;'Inherited'=$Access.IsInherited}
    New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $Properties
  }
}
```

What kind of format recommend me to get out the result from the script, I think CSV is a very good format, but I don´t know if is the correct file format.

Comment: Csv is perfect for exporting ACLs. Don't see why wouldn't it, more so if you have Excel you can easily filter the data when needed.

Comment: The "correct" format is the one that helps you solve your problem. If CSV is easy for you to consume wherever you need this data, then that's an appropriate format.

Answer (score 0):

You can write to CSV format and it will be easier to process them later in excel or another place.

```
$FolderPath = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\FS -Filter * -Recurse -Force 

$collection = @() #Define collection
ForEach ($Folder in $FolderPath) {
  $Acl = Get-Acl -Path $Folder.FullName
  ForEach ($Access in $Acl.Access) {
    $Properties = [ordered]@{'Folder Name'=$Folder.FullName;'Group/User'=$Access.IdentityReference;'Permissions'=$Access.FileSystemRights;'Inherited'=$Access.IsInherited}
    $collection += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $Properties
  }
}
$collection | Export-Csv -LiteralPath C:\ACLInformation.csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```